# Problem with wrapping in 2 lines and truncating long text in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a problem with wrapping and truncating long text in Angular. I want to wrap text in 2 lines and add "..." at the end of the second line if it is longer than 2 lines. I cannot use pure css, because my text couldn't be justify, it should be aligned left. It also should works in Firefox, so I cannot use `-webkit-line-clamp`. Container of my text and my text as well should be responsive.

Any suggestions how to deal with it in Angular 7?

Comment: Hi Ania, please post you code, what did you try?

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: I've tried `text-overflow: ellipsis; ` in css also `-webkit-line-clamp`.

Comment: Did you by any chance solve this in any sattisfactory kind of way?

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you can write an ng-if statement to check the length of the value and if it's greater than a certain number then add ellipses.

`<span ng-if="textValue.length > 100" class="ng-scope">...</span>`

For wrapping you can use:

`word-wrap: break-word;
overflow-wrap: break-word;`

See this CSS-Tricks article for more information
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/

Comment: What is the certain number? How to check it? Because the width of container is changing, the container is responsive. Is there any easy way?

Comment: First see if this give you the result you are looking for. If it is then look into writing CSS Media Queries:
https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/